# Excel formula to convert a number to minutes and seconds is giving me errors

Tags: excel

So in column B I have numbers that represent minutes and seconds e.g. 5.15 Figures to left of . are minutes and to the right are seconds. I am using the formula below to convert the figures to minutes and seconds so that I may calculate the average.
=TIMEVALUE("00:"&SUBSTITUTE(B5,".",":"))

The problem is that whenever the number ends in a zero it converts incorrectly. E.g. 10.30 converts to 00:10:03 and 6.10 converts to 00:06:01. However 5.00 converts correctly. How do I fix my formula?

Comment: See my edit to my answer.

Answer (score -1):

=TIME(,TRUNC(B5),(B5-TRUNC(B5))*100)